Filtering Fact Tables against other in PowerBI
I am currently having two fact tables, which have 4 dimension tables connected to them. However, now I need to filter one fact table against each other. However, setting cross directional filtering is only available for one dimension table at a time.
Is there any workaround for this?
Thank you so much!

if you need to filter one fact table by another, it means that your data model is incorrect. In a proper start schema it's never necessary.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
